# SSLException "Could not generate DH keypair" when calling Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using merchantsdk-2.13.117 (latest version). When executing following code, I receive an SSLException:
`PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);

SetExpressCheckoutResponseType setExpressCheckoutResponse = service.setExpressCheckout(setExpressCheckoutReq);`

Paypal plans to change their SSL communication. As far as I understand, in the future, only "SSL certification VeriSign G5" will be supported. For that reason they implemented this change to their sandbox. Since that change I receive the above mentioned exception (before it worked correctly).

What exactly do I have to change now:

> - switch Java version (using Java 7)
> - change some parameters in `sdkConfig` (see code above), which is a map containing following parameters: acct1.Signature, acct1.Password, acct1.UserName, acct1.AppId, mode
> - Perform some changes on the server (using Tomcat)
> - somthing else?

Here, a part of the console output:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1842)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1825)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:109)
    at com.paypal.core.APIService.makeRequestUsing(APIService.java:177)
    at com.paypal.core.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:265)
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.setExpressCheckout(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:2196)
    at urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.setExpressCheckout(PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.java:2148)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem:

In my project, an old version of Bouncy Castle was included as external library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>138</version>
</dependency>
```

Somehow this leads to problems in using SSL communication. After removing the library completely from my project, the SSL communication with Paypal worked again (with Java 6, 7 and 8).